# Inserir Imagem depois do GridView

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou desenvolvendo um APP no flutter usando um StaggeredGridView no início do build, porém não estou conseguindo inserir uma imagem antes deste grid.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

class TesteMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TesteMenuState createState() => _TesteMenuState();
}

class _TesteMenuState extends State<TesteMenu> {
  Material meuCard(IconData icon, String titulo, int cor) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 15.0,
      shadowColor: Color(0X802196F3),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    titulo,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: new Color(cor),
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      
      //Inserir aqui a imagem...
      usando o Image.asset(ola.jpeg)
      
      
      body: StaggeredGridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          meuCard(Icons.home, "HOME", 0XFFED622B),
          meuCard(Icons.home, "HOME", 0XFFED622B),
          meuCard(Icons.home, "HOME", 0XFFED622B),
          meuCard(Icons.home, "HOME", 0XFFED622B),
        ],
        staggeredTiles: [
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem na sua tela o `Scaffold` e ele possui codificadas 2 propriedades no seu código, o `appBar` e o `body`. Tudo que for desenhar no corpo da tela deve obrigatoriamente estar codificado dentro do `body`.

Para o seu problema, uma das maneiras que pode fazer é envolver o seu `StaggeredGridView` em outro componente. Por exemplo, envolver em um `Column` e inserir um `Expanded` para cada componente (imagem e lista). O `Expanded` te permitirá definir dinamicamente o espaço de cada um dos componentes da coluna de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

**Exemplo de código:**

```
class InformacoesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InformacoesPageState createState() => _InformacoesPageState();
}

class _InformacoesPageState extends State<InformacoesPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Informações"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          /// AQUI É ONDE FICARIA A IMAGEM
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
                child: Image.asset("assets/imagens/drawer_header.png")),
          ),
          /// AQUI É ONDE A LISTA É INSERIDA
          Expanded(
            flex: 9,
            child: Container(
              child: _buildList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Implementação da lista de opções utilizando o [StaggeredGridView]
  StaggeredGridView _buildList() {
    return StaggeredGridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
      mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        meuCard(Icons.home, "HOME", 0XFFED622B),
        meuCard(Icons.home, "HOME", 0XFFED622B),
        meuCard(Icons.home, "HOME", 0XFFED622B),
        meuCard(Icons.home, "HOME", 0XFFED622B),
      ],
      staggeredTiles: [
        StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
        StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
        StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
        StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
      ],
    );
  }

  Material meuCard(IconData icon, String titulo, int cor) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 15.0,
      shadowColor: Color(0X802196F3),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    titulo,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: new Color(cor),
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Outra possibilidade seria de inserir o `expanded` apenas na lista e sem a propriedade `flex`. Nesse caso a altura da imagem poderia se fixada com o `height` do `container` e a lista ocuparia o espaço restante da tela.

**Exemplo 2: (apenas o método build do exemplo anterior sendo alterado aqui)**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Informações"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          /// AQUI É ONDE FICARIA A IMAGEM
          Container(
            child: Image.asset("assets/imagens/drawer_header.png"),
            height: 30,
          ),

          /// AQUI É ONDE A LISTA É INSERIDA
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: _buildList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```